# Cannot select all data from a table php/sql

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != null');
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
}
else{
echo "there are no users"
}
```

I want to select all data from a table however the code above does not work. It echoes/prints out "there are no users." No errors are shown too.

Comment: Test if `$sql` is empty recordset, not boolean `false` which means that the error during query execute occures.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_id != NULL
```

always fails.  Instead, say

```
user_id IS NOT NULL
```

And you need to `->execute` it.

Comment: It still prints out "there are no comments" sadly.

Comment: Another error -- see Answer.

Comment: I forgot to execute the sql statment. That was my issue! I'll still accept your asnwer since it was still a part of my problem.